# how to make tkinter window to stay at bottom?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

```
import Tkinter
from Tkinter import Button
root=Tkinter.Tk()
def close_window (): 
   root.destroy()
w = root.winfo_screenwidth()
root.overrideredirect(1)
root.geometry("200x200+%d+200" %(w-210))
root.configure(background='gray10')
btn = Button(text='X',borderwidth=0,highlightthickness=0,bd=0,command = close_window,height="1",width="1")
btn.pack()
btn.config(bg='gray10', fg='white') 
btn.config(font=('helvetica', 8))
root.mainloop()
```

the window always stay at top of all the windows that i open. i want it to stay at the bottom like the wallpaper. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You're already doing something close. Get the screen height and subtract the height or more of your window.

```
import Tkinter
from Tkinter import Button

root=Tkinter.Tk()
def close_window (): 
    root.destroy()

screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()

root.overrideredirect(1)
root.geometry("200x200+{0}+{1}".format(screen_width-210, screen_height-210))
root.configure(background='gray10')

btn = Button(text='X', borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, bd=0, command=close_window, height="1", width="1")
btn.pack()
btn.config(bg='gray10', fg='white') 
btn.config(font=('helvetica', 8))

root.mainloop()
```